# How to make MongoDB Text Search Find Partial Matches

Tags: mongodb

The find() at the end of this code does NOT find the inserted document.

*Note: I'm using MongoDB version 3.2.15.*

1. Why not?
2. How can I change the index or search parameters so that it's found?

```
  

        db['test'].createIndex(
          {
            name: 'text',
            email: 'text',
            phoneNumber: 'text'
          },
          {
            default_language: 'none',
            name: 'text_index',
            $caseSensitive: false,
            $diacriticSensitive: false,
          } );

        db['test'].insert({
          name: 'Chaney Waste Management',
          email: 'cliffchaney@gmail.com',
          phoneNumber: '(402)555-1212'
        });

        db['test'].find( {
            $text:
              {
                $search: 'manage',
                $language: 'none',
                $caseSensitive: false,
                $diacriticSensitive: false
              }
          } );  // Finds nothing! Why?
```

In case it matters, here is the full result of a db.hostInfo() call:

```
{
    "system" : {
        "currentTime" : ISODate("2017-11-09T02:38:45.379Z"),
        "hostname" : "Cliff-Surface:3001",
        "cpuAddrSize" : 64,
        "memSizeMB" : 16310,
        "numCores" : 4,
        "cpuArch" : "x86_64",
        "numaEnabled" : false
    },
    "os" : {
        "type" : "Windows",
        "name" : "Microsoft Windows 8",
        "version" : "6.2 (build 9200)"
    },
    "extra" : {
        "pageSize" : NumberLong(4096)
    },
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

Comment: Not "partial". You can allow stopwords like "if" "the" with the settings you have, but you still don't match "part of a word". So `"Pi"` would only return `"Pi"` and not `"Pie"` or `"Pixel"` or `"Piranha"`. That's "still" a `$regex` search. See [SERVER-15090](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-15090)

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the answer and link. As one comment put it, "I'm disappointed this doesn't exist yet." Why put all the effort into having a tokenizer, stemming and search scoring without supporting something so minor. Unfortunately, this basically invalidates my use of Mongo Text Indexes entirely.

Comment: Same can be set of a lot of "general purpose database text search" facilities really. If you want more than "basic features", then use a dedicated text search engine. That's sort of why they exist. In short it's not really MongoDB's "bag", or in the works as a priority if the couple of years old issue does not indicate that for you already.